# Can VIM .vimrc highlighting directives be embedded in my edited file?

Tags: vim, highlight

I have many syntax highlighting directives that I use in my documentation that are defined in my `.vim/` files.  While the highlighting is very useful to me, when others view my files, they don't see the highlighting.

I seem to remember that for a `vi` edited file, a vi directive could be included in the file itself that would set tabbing spaces.

How can I achieve the same for highlighting in `vim`?

Comment: Check out [vi.se] for questions on Vim. You'll have to be more specific here, what kind of highlighting rules do you have in your `.vim` files (and which files under `.vim`?) In a file you can use a modeline (comment in first few or last few lines) to set some Vim options, such as tab size, etc. You can't set a whole bunch of syntax highlighting rules there, but you can set the filetype. If you package your syntax rules into a package triggered by filetype, you could use that to share them.

Comment: @filbranden Thanks for your response.  I've just discovered the joy of configuring VIM to do special processing of my data and highlighting in syntax.vim.  I looked over modeline documentation and see its limitations.  I have heard of packaging and will look into that and possibly defining a file type for specific data.  Thanks for direction.  --neil